Learning Python with ZTM, while loop not working
So I'm learning python via ZTM, I'm at the end of while loops 2, and the code block that Andrei wrote isn't breaking (I wrote this thing literally bar for bar)
while True:
   response = input("Say something: ")
   if (response == "bye"):
      break



Are you sure you are inputting the right response? Not reproducible otherwise.

Can you include output from you terminal?

Just added it via screenshot

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Are you sure that's the correct version of code running? `Say something: " before "& C:/Users..." suggests that you've tried running new version of script with old one still running. Try stopping it with Ctrl-C first, restart the script and check again.

Another common error is forgetting to save the changed file before running it.

Based on your screen shot, there are two possibilities:

Another program, presumably an old and incorrect version, is still running when you executed the current and correct program.
For some reason, you didn't actually input "bye" correctly.

Solutions to the two problems:

For the first problem, simply stop the original program and run the correct one. Ctrl + C is the most common way to stop a program, but if you are not executing the code in the terminal, this might not work. In IDEs, like IDLE, there will be a little red square on the menu that allows you to stop a program.
For the second problem, you should add some input validation to your code:

while True:
   response = input("Say something: ")
   while response != 'bye':
       print(f'expect "bye", got {response} instead')
       response = str(input('Say something: '))
       
   if (response == "bye"):
       break

You can also make the validation process easier, like this:
while True:
   response = str(input("Say something: ")).strip().lower()
   if (response == "bye"):
      break

In the above code, the input is first transformed into a string, then stripped of whitespace and converted to lowercase. This way, the original if block is sufficient    validation without the need for an additional while-loop .
